# Google Analytics and Google Map on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am displaying maps in my Android Application. Nowhere in my application I have explicitly invoked www.google-analytics.com, yet I see lots of request going to this website.This is causing my application to be very slow. Also many times I get errors like Unresolved host www.google-analytics.com.

Is it mandatory for the functioning for Google Maps in Android or can we turn this off?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess if Google Maps is using some Google analytics internally, there isnt much that u can do

Comment: This is causing my application to be very slow. Also many times I get errors like Unresolved host www.google-analytics.com.

Comment: I dont think so, I have never faced similar issue ever